# Can I use document.getElementById() with multiple ids?

Tags: javascript, arrays, element, getelementbyid

```
doStuff(document.getElementById("myCircle1" "myCircle2" "myCircle3" "myCircle4"));
```

This doesn't work, so do I need a comma or semi-colon to make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7304535/176469

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` only supports one name at a time and only returns a single node not an array of nodes.  You have several different options:

1. You could implement your own function that takes multiple ids and returns multiple elements.
2. You could use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) that allows you to specify multiple ids in a CSS selector string .
3. You could put a common class names on all those nodes and use `document.getElementsByClassName()` with a single class name.

Examples of each option:

```
doStuff(document.querySelectorAll("#myCircle1, #myCircle2, #myCircle3, #myCircle4"));
```

or:

```
// put a common class on each object
doStuff(document.getElementsByClassName("circles"));
```

or:

```
function getElementsById(ids) {
    var idList = ids.split(" ");
    var results = [], item;
    for (var i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
        item = document.getElementById(idList[i]);
        if (item) {
            results.push(item);
        }
    }
    return(results);
}

doStuff(getElementsById("myCircle1 myCircle2 myCircle3 myCircle4"));
```

Comment: I think `querySelector` accepts CSS syntax, so we need to separate selectors with commas.

Comment: @VisioN - yes, you are right - I corrected that example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, wow this is a mine of information!  Very helpful, thanks I'll investigate these options :D

Comment: can I use a range of numbers like: ````myCirclei```` instead?? @jfriend00

Comment: @MHB - Not with this technique.

Answer (score 21):

This will not work, `getElementById` will query only one element by time.

You can use `document.querySelectorAll("#myCircle1, #myCircle2")` for querying more then one element.

### ES6 or newer

With the new version of the JavaScript, you can also convert the results into an array to easily transverse it.

Example:

```
const elementsList = document.querySelectorAll("#myCircle1, #myCircle2");
const elementsArray = [...elementsList];

// Now you can use cool array prototypes
elementsArray.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);
});
```

### How to query a list of IDs in ES6

Another easy way if you have an array of IDs is to use the language to build your query, example:

```
const ids = ['myCircle1', 'myCircle2', 'myCircle3'];
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(ids.map(id => `#${id}`).join(', '));
```

Answer (score 10):

### No, it won't work.

[`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) method accepts only one argument.

However, you may always set classes to the elements and use [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) instead. Another option for modern browsers is to use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) method:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#myCircle1, #myCircle2, #myCircle3, #myCircle4");
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using ES5 array methods:

```
["myCircle1","myCircle2","myCircle3","myCircle4"] // Array of IDs
.map(document.getElementById, document)           // Array of elements
.forEach(doStuff);
```

Then `doStuff` will be called once for each element, and will receive 3 arguments: the element, the index of the element inside the array of elements, and the array of elements.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementByID` is exactly that - get an element by id.

Maybe you want to give those elements a `circle` class and [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName)

Comment: getElementsByClassName doesn't seem to be working. I'm using SVG. In my SVG object I've written class="circle".  Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById()` only takes one argument. You can give them a class name and use `getElementsByClassName()` .

Comment: You'd think it would then get all the cases, but you will have to specify which one you're reaching for, so `getElementsByClassName()[0]` for the first one, `..[1]` for the second one, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if something like this works in js, in PHP and Python which i use quite often it is possible.
Maybe just use for loop like:

```
function doStuff(){
    for(i=1; i<=4; i++){
        var i = document.getElementById("myCiricle"+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good one for sure. Easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Vulgo has the right idea on this thread. I believe his solution is the easiest of the bunch, although his answer could have been a little more in-depth. Here is something that worked for me. I have provided an example.

```
<h1 id="hello1">Hello World</h1>
<h2 id="hello2">Random</h2>
<button id="click">Click To Hide</button>

<script>

  document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', function(){
    doStuff();
  });

  function doStuff() {
    for(var i=1; i<=2; i++){
        var el = document.getElementById("hello" + i);
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

</script>
```

Obviously just change the integers in the for loop to account for however many elements you are targeting, which in this example was 2.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it, is to define a function, and pass it a parameter of the ID's name that you want to grab from the DOM, then every time you want to grab an ID and store it inside an array, then you can call the function

```
<p id="testing">Demo test!</p>

function grabbingId(element){
    var storeId = document.getElementById(element);

    return storeId;
}


grabbingId("testing").syle.color = "red";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this whit array and for loop.

```
<p id='fisrt'>??????</p>
<p id='second'>??????</p>
<p id='third'>??????</p>
<p id='forth'>??????</p>
<p id='fifth'>??????</p>
<button id="change" onclick="changeColor()">color red</button>
<script>

    var ids = ['fisrt','second','third','forth','fifth'];

    function changeColor() {
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
          document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.color='red';
 }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you want to create an or-like construction, where either of the elements is available on the page, you could use `querySelector`. querySelector tries locating the first id in the list, and if it can't be found continues to the next until it finds an element.

The difference with `querySelectorAll` is that it only finds a single element, so looping is not necessary.

```js
document.querySelector('#myCircle1, #myCircle2, #myCircle3, #myCircle4');
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked flawles something like this

```
doStuff(

    document.getElementById("myCircle1") ,

    document.getElementById("myCircle2") ,

    document.getElementById("myCircle3") ,

    document.getElementById("myCircle4")

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery or similar to get access to the collection of elements in only one sentence. Of course, you need to put something like this in your html's "head" section:

> ```
> <script type='text/javascript' src='url/to/my/jquery.1.xx.yy.js' ...>
> ```

So here is the magic:

.- First of all let's supose that you have some divs with IDs as you wrote, i.e.,

> ```
>  ...some html...
>  <div id='MyCircle1'>some_inner_html_tags</div>
>  ...more html...
>  <div id='MyCircle2'>more_html_tags_here</div>
>  ...blabla...
>  <div id='MyCircleN'>more_and_more_tags_again</div>
>  ...zzz...
> ```

.- With this 'spell' jQuery will return a collection of objects representing  all div elements with IDs containing the entire string "myCircle" anywhere:

> ```
>  $("div[id*='myCircle']")
> ```

This is all! Note that you get rid of details like the numeric suffix, that you can manipulate all the divs in a single sentence, animate them... Voilá!

> ```
>  $("div[id*='myCircle']").addClass("myCircleDivClass").hide().fadeIn(1000);
> ```

Prove this in your browser's script console (press F12) right now!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by jfriend00,

> document.getElementById() only supports one name at a time and only returns a single node not an array of nodes.

However, here's some example code I created which you can give one or a comma separated list of id's. It will give you one or many elements in an array. If there are any errors, it will return an array with an Error as the only entry.

```
function safelyGetElementsByIds(ids){
    if(typeof ids !== 'string') return new Error('ids must be a comma seperated string of ids or a single id string');
    ids = ids.split(",");
    let elements = [];
    for(let i=0, len = ids.length; i<len; i++){
        const currId = ids[i];
        const currElement = (document.getElementById(currId) || new Error(currId + ' is not an HTML Element'));
        if(currElement instanceof Error) return [currElement];
        elements.push(currElement);
    };
    return elements;
}

safelyGetElementsByIds('realId1'); //returns [<HTML Element>]
safelyGetElementsByIds('fakeId1'); //returns [Error : fakeId1 is not an HTML Element]
safelyGetElementsByIds('realId1', 'realId2', 'realId3'); //returns [<HTML Element>,<HTML Element>,<HTML Element>]
safelyGetElementsByIds('realId1', 'realId2', 'fakeId3'); //returns [Error : fakeId3 is not an HTML Element]
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar, and used this:

```
<script>
  function copyClipboard(target) {
    var copyText = document.getElementById(target).innerHTML;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
   } 
</script>

//html
<button onclick="copyClipboard(getAttribute('id'))" id="grav">123
```

This way I could obtain the object id in short code.

Answer (score -1):

here is the solution

```
if (
  document.getElementById('73536573').value != '' &&
  document.getElementById('1081743273').value != '' &&
  document.getElementById('357118391').value != '' &&
  document.getElementById('1238321094').value != '' &&
  document.getElementById('1118122010').value != ''
  ) {
code
  }
```

Answer (score -5):

You can do it with document.getElementByID   Here is how.

```
function dostuff (var here) {
  if(add statment here) {
  document.getElementById('First ID'));
  document.getElementById('Second ID'));
  }
}
```

There you go! xD