# volumeslider for both html5 audio and video

Tags: java, jquery, html, audio, video

Now I have searched the internet far and wide for a script or help to create a slider that controls both HTML5 video and audio at the same time. But alas I found no such thing.

So I come to you in hope you will help me with this pickle :-)

Project: 
I am trying to create a website that provides both video and audio at the same time, but they are hidden. It's suppost to stay in the background, so there need to be a volume slider so you can adjust the sounds for your own liking.

```
<div class="hidden">    
<audio id="audio1" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" loop><source src="jazz.mp3" /></audio>
<video id="video1" width="1" height="1" autoplay="autoplay" loop> <source src="fireplace.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
<audio id="audio2" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" loop><source src="rain.mp3" /></audio> 
</div>
```

Tried to at the start to create a script that turned the music down at page load, but didn't work

```
<script language="javascript">
var a = document.getElementById('audio1','audio2','video1');
a.volume = 0.1;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` accepts only one id as parameter. See this answer for other options [GetElementByID - Multiple IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14408904/1333677)

Your code should run if you write it like this:

```
var a1 = document.getElementById('audio1');
var a2 = document.getElementById('audio2');
var v1 = document.getElementById('video1');
a1.volume = a2.volume = v1.volume = 0.8;
```