# Find by Id two elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath

I have the 2 Xpath below that don't have Id nor class. I want to find the element with "id=RTY_183" or "id=RTY_189".

```
//*[@id='RTY_183']
//*[@id='RTY_189']
```

I've tried `regex` and `or` but don't work, like this:

with `OR`

```
document.evaluate("//*[@id='RTY_183' or @id='RTY_189' ]", document.body, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.click();
```

and with `regex`

```
document.evaluate("//*[@id='RTY_18[3,9]']", document.body, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.click();
```

Is possible? what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetElementByID - Multiple IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408891/getelementbyid-multiple-ids)

Comment: @SudhirOjha I've tried from the lik you shared like this `document.querySelectorAll("#RTY_183, #RTY_189").click();` but doesn't work. May you help me to fix what I'm fdoing wrong please.

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: @SudhirOjha Sorry which code? I already show the code I tested in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below Xpath.

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'RTY_18')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Xpath you suggest can be used with `document.querySelectorAll()` or with `document.evaluate()`? But the issue is there are more Xpath in the same window that are like `RTY_182, RTY_185, RTY_187, etc` and from all I only want to do click on the two ending in 3 or 9.