# Increase and decrease font size not working with all paragraphs javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
**I have many separated paragraphs in one HTML page all of them have the same id **id=text** when I use the onmousemove event only the first paragraph can increase and decrease the font size not all of them although they have the same id  .**
```

This is the javascript code:

```
function incfont(){
    var t= document.getElementById('fontsize').value;
    var x= document.getElementById('text');
    x.style.fontSize = t+"px";
```

**Here are an example of paragraphs with the same id **

```
<p id="test">paragraph 1 </p>
<p id="test">paragraph 2 </p>
```

Comment: You better use class there, you shoud not duplicate ids

Answer (score 0):

As you have many paragraphs, you shouldn't be setting an id, but a class.

getElementById() only gets a single element.

Please refer to this question and the selected answer. [GetElementByID - Multiple IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408891/getelementbyid-multiple-ids)

Answer (score 0):

In Html

```
<p class="test">paragraph 1 </p>
<p class="test">paragraph 2 </p>
```

In Script

```
function incfont(){
    var t= document.getElementById('fontsize').value;
    var x= document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].style.fontSize = t+"px";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Html

```
//Instead of Id use class in HTML
<p class="test">paragraph 1 </p>
<p class="test">paragraph 2 </p>
```

In Script

```
function incfont(){
    var t= document.getElementById('fontsize').value;
    //Here you need to change getElemetById to getElementsByClassName because getElementById() only gets a single element
    var x= document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    x.style.fontSize = t+"px";
    }
}
```