# Two blocks in getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript. Let's say I have a block

```
<div class="nav">
  <div id="rectangle" class="rectangle">
    Content...
  </div>
</div>
```

And I am using this block in some script

```
document.getElementById('navShareLink');
```

But now I want to add another one to the `nav` block, let's say

```
<div class="nav">
  <div id="rectangle" class="rectangle">
    Content...
  </div>

  <div id="to-top" class="to-top">
    Content...
  </div>
</div>
```

The question is, can I use two blocks at once in this line, like

```
document.getElementById('rectangle', 'to-top');
```

If not, what are the options?

Comment: There is a good explanation of this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408891/getelementbyid-multiple-ids).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GetElementByID - Multiple IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408891/getelementbyid-multiple-ids)

Comment: It has constant lookup speed anyway, since the ids are like the hashes in a hashmap. So It's fine to call it twice, performance wise.