# javascript youtube : set radio button to public

Tags: javascript

i have this code not working below,i am trying my best to resolve the issue by testing out different methods and i am not able to have any success so far.
kindly look into it and let me know.

```
WV.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('radioLabel').click();"
```

here is some HTML code I got from the web browser. kindly look into it and check

```
<div id="first-container" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select">
  
    <tp-yt-paper-radio-button class="container-radios style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select" name="FIRST_CONTAINER" role="radio" tabindex="0" toggles="" checked="" aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="false" active=""><!--css_build_mark:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_button.tp.yt.paper.radio.button.css.js--><!--css_build_scope:tp-yt-paper-radio-button--><!--css_build_styles:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_button.tp.yt.paper.radio.button.css.js--><div id="radioContainer" style-target="container" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"><div id="offRadio" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"></div><div id="onRadio" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"></div></div><div id="radioLabel" style-target="label" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button">
      Save or publish
    </div></tp-yt-paper-radio-button>
  <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>
  <p id="visibility-title" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select" hidden="">
    Save or publish
  </p>
  <p class="visibility-description style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select" hidden="">Make your video <b class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select">public</b>, <b class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select">unlisted</b> or <b class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select">private</b></p>
  <p class="visibility-description style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select" hidden="">Only <b class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select">Public</b> or <b class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select">Unlisted</b> can be selected when going live from mobile. Unlisted is recommended for testing your stream.</p>
  
    
    <tp-yt-paper-radio-group id="privacy-radios" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select" autofocus="" role="radiogroup" tabindex="0"><!--css_build_mark:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_group.tp.yt.paper.radio.group.css.js--><!--css_build_scope:tp-yt-paper-radio-group--><!--css_build_styles:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_group.tp.yt.paper.radio.group.css.js-->
      
        <dom-if class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>

        
          <tp-yt-paper-radio-button id="private-radio-button" name="PRIVATE" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select" role="radio" tabindex="-1" toggles="" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><!--css_build_mark:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_button.tp.yt.paper.radio.button.css.js--><!--css_build_scope:tp-yt-paper-radio-button--><!--css_build_styles:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_button.tp.yt.paper.radio.button.css.js--><div id="radioContainer" style-target="container" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"><div id="offRadio" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"></div><div id="onRadio" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"></div></div><div id="radioLabel" style-target="label" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button">Private</div></tp-yt-paper-radio-button>
          <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>
          <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>
          <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>
        <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>

        <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>

        <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>
      
        <dom-if class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>

        <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>

        
          <tp-yt-paper-radio-button name="UNLISTED" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select iron-selected" role="radio" tabindex="0" toggles="" aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true" checked="" active=""><!--css_build_mark:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_button.tp.yt.paper.radio.button.css.js--><!--css_build_scope:tp-yt-paper-radio-button--><!--css_build_styles:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_button.tp.yt.paper.radio.button.css.js--><div id="radioContainer" style-target="container" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"><div id="offRadio" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"></div><div id="onRadio" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"></div></div><div id="radioLabel" style-target="label" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button">Unlisted</div></tp-yt-paper-radio-button>
          <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>

          <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>
        <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>

        <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>
      
        
          <tp-yt-paper-radio-button name="PUBLIC" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select" role="radio" tabindex="-1" toggles="" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><!--css_build_mark:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_button.tp.yt.paper.radio.button.css.js--><!--css_build_scope:tp-yt-paper-radio-button--><!--css_build_styles:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_button.tp.yt.paper.radio.button.css.js--><div id="radioContainer" style-target="container" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"><div id="offRadio" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"></div><div id="onRadio" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"></div></div><div id="radioLabel" style-target="label" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button">Public</div></tp-yt-paper-radio-button>
          <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>
          
            <div class="instant-premiere-container style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select">
              <ytcp-checkbox-lit id="enable-premiere-checkbox" track-click="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select" disabled="" aria-disabled="true" tabindex="-1" aria-checked="false" role="checkbox"><!---->
    <div id="checkbox-container" class="style-scope ytcp-checkbox-lit">
      <div id="checkbox" class="style-scope ytcp-checkbox-lit">
        <!--?lit$8778237695$--><!--?-->
      </div>
      <!--?lit$8778237695$-->
    </div>
    <!--?lit$8778237695$--><div class="label style-scope ytcp-checkbox-lit">
      <!--?lit$8778237695$-->Set as instant Premiere
      
    </div>
    
  </ytcp-checkbox-lit>
              <ytcp-icon-tooltip compact="" icon-code="icons:help-outline" position="horizontal-end" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"><!--css_build_mark:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_icon_tooltip.ytcp.icon.tooltip.css.js--><!--css-build:shady--><!--css_build_scope:ytcp-icon-tooltip--><!--css_build_styles:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.shared.ui.styles.yt_base_styles.yt.base.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.styles.ytcp_styles.ytcp.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_icon_tooltip.ytcp.icon.tooltip.css.js--><tp-yt-iron-icon id="icon" class="style-scope ytcp-icon-tooltip" compact="" tabindex="0" aria-label="When you set your video as an instant Premiere, you and your viewers can watch it together at the
  same time." aria-describedby="goog_1261315836"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false" class="style-scope tp-yt-iron-icon" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><g class="style-scope tp-yt-iron-icon"><path d="M11 18h2v-2h-2v2zm1-16C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8zm0-14c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4h2c0-1.1.9-2 2-2s2 .9 2 2c0 2-3 1.75-3 5h2c0-2.25 3-2.5 3-5 0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4z" class="style-scope tp-yt-iron-icon"></path></g></svg><!--css_build_mark:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_iron_icon.tp.yt.iron.icon.css.js--><!--css_build_scope:tp-yt-iron-icon--><!--css_build_styles:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_iron_icon.tp.yt.iron.icon.css.js-->
</tp-yt-iron-icon>
<ytcp-paper-tooltip for="icon" type="explanatory" class="style-scope ytcp-icon-tooltip"><!--css_build_mark:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_paper_tooltip.ytcp_paper_tooltip.ytcp.paper.tooltip.css.js--><!--css-build:shady--><!--css_build_scope:ytcp-paper-tooltip--><!--css_build_styles:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.shared.ui.styles.yt_base_styles.yt.base.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.styles.ytcp_styles.ytcp.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_paper_tooltip.ytcp_paper_tooltip.ytcp.paper.tooltip.css.js-->
<ytcp-paper-tooltip-placeholder role="tooltip" class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip" disable-upgrade="" id="goog_1261315836">
  <div id="slot-wrapper" class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip"></div>
  <div id="tooltip-placeholder-fake-slot" class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip">
  <ytcp-paper-tooltip-body class="style-scope ytcp-icon-tooltip"><!--css_build_mark:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_paper_tooltip.ytcp_paper_tooltip_body.ytcp.paper.tooltip.body.css.js--><!--css-build:shady--><!--css_build_scope:ytcp-paper-tooltip-body--><!--css_build_styles:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.shared.ui.styles.yt_base_styles.yt.base.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.styles.ytcp_styles.ytcp.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_paper_tooltip.ytcp_paper_tooltip_body.ytcp.paper.tooltip.body.css.js-->
  <p class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body"><yt-formatted-string class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body">When you set your video as an instant Premiere, you and your viewers can watch it together at the
  same time.</yt-formatted-string></p>
<dom-repeat as="p" class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body"></dom-repeat>
<dom-repeat as="message" class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body"></dom-repeat>


  

  <p class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body">
    <ytcp-anchor class="link style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body"><!--css_build_mark:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_anchor.ytcp.anchor.css.js--><!--css-build:shady--><!--css_build_scope:ytcp-anchor--><!--css_build_styles:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.shared.ui.styles.yt_base_styles.yt.base.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.styles.ytcp_styles.ytcp.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_anchor.ytcp.anchor.css.js--><a id="anchor" class="remove-default-style style-scope ytcp-anchor" href="https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9080341?hl=en-GB" target="_blank">
  <dom-if class="style-scope ytcp-anchor"></dom-if>
  <span class="text style-scope ytcp-anchor">
    
    
    
    Learn more
  </span>
  <dom-if class="style-scope ytcp-anchor"></dom-if>
</a>
</ytcp-anchor>
  </p>
<dom-repeat as="link" class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body"></dom-repeat>
</ytcp-paper-tooltip-body>
</div>
  <dom-if class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip"></dom-if>
</ytcp-paper-tooltip-placeholder>
</ytcp-paper-tooltip>
</ytcp-icon-tooltip>
            </div>
          <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>
        <dom-if class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>

        <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>

        <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>

        <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>
      <dom-repeat as="option" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-repeat>
    
</tp-yt-paper-radio-group>
  <dom-if restamp="" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select"></dom-if>
  <ytcp-form-error-tip always-visible="" anchor-selector="#first-container" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select" position="top" hidden=""><!--css_build_mark:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.forms.ytcp_form_error_tip.ytcp.form.error.tip.css.js--><!--css-build:shady--><!--css_build_scope:ytcp-form-error-tip--><!--css_build_styles:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.shared.ui.styles.yt_base_styles.yt.base.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.styles.ytcp_styles.ytcp.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.forms.ytcp_form_error_tip.ytcp.form.error.tip.css.js--><div id="message" aria-role="alert" aria-live="polite" class="style-scope ytcp-form-error-tip">
  
</div><div id="tail" class="style-scope ytcp-form-error-tip"></div></ytcp-form-error-tip>
</div>
```

I tried currently what is posted above it doesn't seem to set the check to public. wonder why.

am still trying and also hoping that anybody from here can also give little support thank you.

i want to set the checkbox to public thats all I need. just a code that will click it or mark it as checked.

=================

code updated please check below

```
<tp-yt-paper-radio-button name="PUBLIC" class="style-scope ytcp-video-visibility-select" role="radio" tabindex="-1" toggles="" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false"><!--css_build_mark:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_button.tp.yt.paper.radio.button.css.js--><!--css_build_scope:tp-yt-paper-radio-button--><!--css_build_styles:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_paper_radio_button.tp.yt.paper.radio.button.css.js--><div id="radioContainer" style-target="container" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"><div id="offRadio" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"></div><div id="onRadio" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button"></div></div><div id="radioLabel" style-target="label" class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-radio-button">Public</div></tp-yt-paper-radio-button>
```

Comment: you have 3 objects with id "radioLabel" in your html above. `document.getElementById('radioLabel')` will always get the first one (which is the "PRIVATE" one).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408891/getelementbyid-multiple-ids

Comment: one possible solution: give each private / unlisted / public a _different_ id. Then choose this one.

Comment: post 1 updated with html code for checkbox please look at it

Comment: there are still 3 objects with the same id. Edit: 4, actually. Your getElementById will get the first one, which is not the one you want.

Comment: its from youtube. i cannot set id for it.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("PUBLIC").getElementById('radioLabel')` -> this should point to the correct div.