# credit card from submit and validate

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to get the code right for submitting and validating a credit card form. I have tried changing different js codes but can't seem to get it right there is something I am missing as you can see I am new to js.

I have the go to other website button working just can't get the submit button to do anything

here is the HTML i have been working with i have validated this with no errors but something just not working Please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>CC FORM</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<header></header>
<form id="ccdetails">
<fieldset>
<legend>Customer details</legend> <br>
<table>
    <tr id="fname"><td>First Name </td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr id="lname"><td>Last Name </td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr id= "postcode"><td>Postcode </td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr id="email"><td>Email </td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>  
<fieldset>
<legend>Payment Details</legend><br>
<table>
    <tr><td>Credit Card </td><td>
    <select name="cardtype" id="cardtype">
    <option value="Visa">Visa</option>
    <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
    <option value="American Express">American Express</option>
    </select></td></tr>
    <tr id="c_num"><td>Card Number </td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr id="ccv"><td>CVV </td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Expiry MM/YY 
    <select name="month" id="month">
        <option value="number">1</option>
        <option value="number">2</option>
        <option value="number">3</option>
        <option value="number">4</option>
        <option value="number">5</option>
        <option value="number">6</option>
        <option value="number">7</option>
        <option value="number">8</option>
        <option value="number">9</option>
        <option value="number">10</option>
        <option value="number">11</option>
        <option value="number">12</option>
    </select>   
    <td>/
    <select name="year" id="year">
        <option value="number">2023</option>
        <option value="number">2024</option>
        <option value="number">2025</option>
        <option value="number">2026</option>
        <option value="number">2027</option>
        <option value="number">2028</option>
        <option value="number">2029</option>
        <option value="number">2030</option>
        <option value="number">2031</option>
        <option value="number">2032</option>
    </select></td>
</table>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="button" onclick="submitform ()">Submit</button>
 <script src="../js/gotoweb.js">
</script>
  <button type="button" onclick="form_help">Help</button>
 

  <br>
  <br>

<button type="button" onclick="goToWebsite()">Go to other Pages</button>
 <script src="../js/gotoweb.js">
</script>

</form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my js i have been using i know it is something in here i just cant seem to find it. i am more intersted in the submitform area as i have the goto other website working.

```
function goToWebsite () {
    let validChoice = false;
    let errorMessage = "Payment Options\n";
    
    while (!validChoice) {
        const usersChoice  = prompt(errorMessage + "\n1.Postbillpay \n2.Afterpay \n3.Applepay");
        if (usersChoice === null) {
            return;
        }
        switch (usersChoice) {
            case "1":
                window.open("https://www.postbillpay.com.au/","blank", "width=800,height=800");
                vaildChoice=true;
                break;
            case "2":
                window.open("https://www.afterpay.com/en-AU","blank", "width=800,height=800");
                vaildChoice=true;
                break;
            case "3":
                window.open("https://www.apple.com/au/apple-pay/","blank", "width=800,height=800");
                vaildChoice=true;
                break;
            default:
            errorMessage = "invalid choice. ";
            break;
        }
    }
}
function submitform () {

// Check all fields have been filled in
const required_fields = document.getElementById ("c_num","month","year", "ccv", "fname" , "lname", "postcode", "emai");
let all_fields_filled = true;
for (const field of required_fields) {
  if (!field) {
    all_fields_filled = false;
    break;
  }
}
if (all_fields_filled) {
  // Proceed to the next field 
} else {
  display ("Please check all fields");
}

// Check email is valid
const email_address = document.getElementById("email");
if (email_address.length < 8 || !email_address.includes('@') || !email_address.includes('.')) {
  console.log("Invalid email address. Please enter a valid email address.");
} else {
  // Proceed to the next field
}
// Check post code has 4 digits
const postcode = document.getElementById('postcode').value;
if (postcode.length !== 4 || isNaN(postcode)) {
  alert('Please enter a valid postcode');
} else {
  // proceed with the rest of the form
}

// Credit card field only contains 16 numbers
const c_num = document.getElementById('c_num').value;
if (/^\d+$/.test(c_num) && c_num.length === 16) {
  // proceed to the next field 
} else {
  alert('Invalid credit card number');
}

// CVV only has 3 numbers
const ccv = document.getElementById('ccv').value;
if (ccv.length === 3) {
  // proceed with the rest of the form
} else {
  alert('Please enter a valid CCV');
}

// Check if card is not expired
const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);

const expiryMonth = document.getElementById('month').value;
const expiryYear = document.getElementById('year').value;

if (currentYear > expiryYear || (currentYear === expiryYear && currentMonth > expiryMonth)) {
  alert('The card has expired, please enter a valid card');
} else {
  // proceed with submit form
}           
}
```

i have also tried using js validater but to no effect

Comment: You can not get the feilds using `const required_fields = document.getElementById ("c_num","month","year", "ccv", "fname" , "lname", "postcode", "emai");` you need individual fields. You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408891/can-i-use-document-getelementbyid-with-multiple-ids)